# Angular 4: Custom errorHandler with Subject Or BehaviorSubject not working

Tags: angular, angular-errorhandler

I am adding custom error handler with event to emit, on error I want to emit error messages to main component to show it on top of page.

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor() { }
  errors: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
   //errors: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  technicalError= false;
  handleError(error) {
        const httpCode = error.status;
         if (httpCode !== undefined) {
           this.errors.next(error._body);
           //this.technicalError = true;
         }else {
           console.log('Error--' + error);
           // throw error;
         }
        }

    }
```

main-component.ts

```
@Component{
 providers: {GlobalErrorhandler}
}
export class MainComponent {

constructor(private glbError:GlobalErrorHandler){
}

onInit(){
this.glbError.errors.subscribe({
body=> {
this.technicalErrors = body;
}
});
}

showError(){
 throw new error();//consider it as http error with 400 or 403, this is sample one
}
}
```

Here on error received from backend it triggers the handleError method but it doesnot emits the error message to the MainComponent.

**Updated question**
Also added below line in MainModule

`providers: [{provide:ErrorHandler, useClass:GlobalErrorHandler}]`

Comment: perhaps you just omitted it, but you don't have a `technicalErrors` property in MainComponent. What result are you expecting in your MainComponent?

Comment: can you try out answer , let me know works if not works for you

Comment: @JPLew I have copy pasted only few lines of code which is required, I have initialized  `technicalErrors` properly,

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion its better you do not expose full subject object like this

```
errors: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

it should be like this

```
private errorsSubejct: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

get errors():Observable<any> {
    return this.errorsSubject.asObservable();
}
```

---

can you try like this

```
this.glbError.errors.asObservable().subscribe({
body=> {
this.technicalErrors = body;
}
});
```

so your code will be like this , component.ts

```
@Component{
 providers: {GlobalErrorhandler}
}
export class MainComponent {

technicalErrors: any[];

constructor(private glbError:GlobalErrorHandler){
}

onInit(){
this.technicalErrors = [];
this.glbError.errors.asObservable().subscribe({
body=> {
this.technicalErrors = body;
}
});
}

showError(){
 throw new error();//consider it as http error with 400 or 403, this is sample one
}
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let err of technicalErrors">
  {{err|json}}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain me why it is not working with `Subject ` or `BehaviourSubject`? I have used same technique inside my other services but here it is not detecting changes.

Comment: @SunilAjagekar - in you code all looks fine but `technicalErrors` is not defined in you code that what i can see