# Angular: Why don't subscriptions to a Subject in my custom ErrorHandler fire?

Tags: angular, error-handling

I have an Angular app with a custom `ErrorHandler`. My goal is to allow components (say, the `AppComponent`) to be notified when a global error occurs so that they can present it in the interface. I implemented this by extending `ErrorHandler` (as described in [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ErrorHandler)), and I added a `Subject` property called `onError$` which emits a value when `handleError()` is called. I then inject `ErrorHandlerService` into the app component, and it subscribes to `onError$`. Here's a minimal repro (also a [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-d1fr41?file=src/app/app.component.ts)):

## Repro

### error-handler.service.ts

```js
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ErrorHandlerService implements ErrorHandler {
  onError$ = new Subject<string>();
  
  handleError(error: any): void {
    this.onError$.next(`An error: ${error}`);
    console.log("Hi from ErrorHandlerService! I called next().");
  }
}
```

### app.module.ts

```js
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './error-handler.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorHandlerService }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ErrorHandlerService } from './error-handler.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.less']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = "SO Angular Error Question";

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorHandlerService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.errorService.onError$.asObservable().subscribe(error => {
      console.log("Hi from the subscription to the onError$ subject!", error);
    });

    throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

## Expected result

When I manually throw the error in `app.component.ts`, I expect the `console.log` statement in `ErrorHandlerService` to run, and then I expect the subscription callback in `AppComponent` to run its `console.log`, resulting in two messages being printed to the console from my app.

## Observed result

The `console.log` from `ErrorHandlerService` happens, but the one in `AppComponent`'s subscription callback doesn't.

[image: First console log statement runs, but the second doesn't]

## My question

Why does the callback for the subscription in `AppComponent` not occur?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49366618/angular-4-custom-errorhandler-with-subject-or-behaviorsubject-not-working) seems related, but it doesn't have an accepted answer, and adding `.asObservable()` before subscribing in the component doesn't resolve the problem. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49474788/angular-material-snackbar-and-custom-errorhandler-to-notify-error) is also related and "solves" the problem by calling a method on an error reporting service explicitly in the error handler, but I'm still curious why my solution doesn't work.

My suspicion is that despite the fact that my `ErrorHandlerService` is marked with `providedIn: 'root'`, the framework creates an instance to act as the global error handler, and the `AppComponent` is receiving a second one, but I can't find documentation about this behavior anywhere. Any help appreciated!

Comment: It works in my edited StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5ar4zm?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool question, nicely formatted

### tl;dr

```
//in app.component.ts
constructor(@Inject(ErrorHandler) private errorService: ErrorsService,
```

### This is a (uncommon) dependancy injection problem

In your `app.module.ts` you have

```
providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorsService }],
```

The token is `ErrorHandler`, the provided thing is `ErrorsService`

When you inject a service in your constructor like

```
constructor(private errorService: ErrorsService
```

That's shorthand for

```
constructor(@Inject(ErrorsService) private errorService: ErrorsService
```

Here the token is `ErrorsService`, the provided thing is `ErrorsService`

Angular looks for providers of **tokens** to fulfill the DI, so the fix is to use the right token.

Comment: This does fix the problem! Thanks for answering. I'm still not totally sure why my original solution doesn't work, though - I expected that because I'm decorating my service with `providedIn: root`, there would only ever be one instance of it in the DI container. So apparently the DI system can resolve multiple instances of something provided in root when multiple injection tokens ask for it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Remove the `providedIn: root` and try `constructor(private errorsService: ErrorsService)`, you'll get an error saying the provider isn't found. You're right that there's only one instance when you use `providedIn: root` (assuming you don't provide it elsewhere), but it's for the token  `ErrorsService`.  You're providing `ErrorService` for the token `ErrorHandler` in `app.module`  with the line `providers: [{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: ErrorsService }]`

Comment: So it's not resolving multiple instances for something provided in root, there's one instance of `ErrorService` for the token `ErrorHandler` and one instance for the token `ErrorService`. It's like a key-value storage system, but it's token-dependancy.

Comment: Thank you for the additional explanation! This has been incredibly helpful.